# C# how to use the \ character in a char datatype

Tags: c#

I would like to trim a \ character from the end of the string. How is this done?

```
MyString.Value.TrimEnd('\');
```

simple doesn't work, and produces a newline in constant error, please help

Comment: So this isn't a `TrimEnd` issue at all, but a problem related to string/character constant use in source code. Perhaps you could edit to change the title of the question to reflect this?

Comment: @peSHir - done! feel free though to make any further editions as you see fit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change this to

```
MyString.Value.TrimEnd('\\');
```

The slash has to be escaped.

Answer (score 3):

`\` is an escape character, use `\\` instead.

Bobby

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
MyString.Value.TrimEnd((char)92);
```